# Should we specifically discredit hate and racist sites as notable sources?

Tags: discussion, questions

This question is receiving downvotes:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/37424/5337

Needless to say, the claim in question is extremely offensive and stupid.  I find myself hovering over the downvote button, but I didn't click as I'm not sure if, within our rules, we have valid reasons to downvote or vote to close.  On the one hand, it's not fair to blame the messenger.  On the other hand, I'm not sure it is our role to duplicate paragraph by paragraph Hitlers *Mein Kampf* and disprove it all.  Should we specifically discredit racist and hate sites as notable sources?